# Yii: How to set unique table alias for model

Tags: php, yii

I'am working on two models.

1. Credentials
2. Messages

Credentials model has a default scope method, where I've added **addNotInCondition** to filter blocked users. Here is my code

```
public function defaultScope() {
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
  $criteria->addNotInCondition("t.id", BanUser::model()->bannedUsers);
  return $criteria;
}
```

This works fine. But While accessing credentials model from Messages model, it gives me error. **Unknown column 't.id'**. (BELONGS_TO relation is defined in messages model)

```
$message->credential; //this generate error.
```

What could be solution to this problem. I know this is due table aliases. I'm stuck here. Please help.

Comment: did you try using the original table name instead of 't'??

Comment: @Letmesee Yes I tried. It didn't work by full table name

Comment: can you just post the query from the log that yii is actually executing?

Answer (score 3):

You can set table alias for model by its default scope method:

```
/**
* @return array default scope (applies only to SELECT statements)
*/
public function defaultScope () {
    return array(
        'alias' => $this->tableName(),
    );
}
```

Then use alias elsewhere too, e.g. in search:

```
public function search () {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = $this->tableName();
    $criteria->compare( $criteria->alias.'.id', $this->id );
    return new CActiveDataProvider( $this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can get current model alias name like this:

```
public function defaultScope() {
  $alias = $this->getTableAlias(false,false);

  $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

  $banned = array();

  foreach(BanUser::model()->bannedUsers as $user)
      $banned[] = $user->id;

  $criteria->addNotInCondition($alias.".id", $banned);
  return $criteria;
}
```

Then I'm not sure about *BanUser::model()->bannedUsers*. [Manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addNotInCondition-detail) tells us that
addNotInCondition accepts array (i.e. ('val1','val2','val3','etc')). If I remember
well, relational fields aren't arrays of values, but are objects.

Comment: it worked though, but I can't access Credential->id. It says **Trying to get property of non-object**.

Comment: It means after applying condition, there are 0 users meeting this condition. I'll update an answer, and you'll give it a try

Comment: Thanks for the edit. BanUser::Model()->bannedUsers is already returning array. (by magic method), I tried it out by checking if bannedUsers is empty but it didn't work. Let me tell you that, I want to filter those messages sent by bannedusers. Do you think should I use another approach like adding condition in Messages model? this could solve problem but I wanted to automate this step.